# How to tokenize double dots as separate tokens in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have code like that:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_md')
doc = nlp('92637 Weiden i.d.OPf..')
tokens = list(doc)
```

So, tokens looks like that:

```
92637
Weiden
i.d
.
OPf
..
```

How can I split last (**double-dot**) token into two tokens with **single-dot**?
It's necessary for fit into NER-labeling.

So, I expecting that:

```
92637
Weiden
i.d
.
OPf
.
.
```

Comment: Dot is not a common token, it treated specially. Can you clarify is you question only concerns 2 dots? 3,4 dots or any other characters? Dots in the middle or at the end of a sentence? Can you provide several exhaustive positive and negative examples?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov in this situation, we need tokens consisting of two points - split one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_md')
nlp.tokenizer.explain('92637 Weiden i.d.OPf..')
```

You'll find out:

```
[('TOKEN', '92637'),
 ('TOKEN', 'Weiden'),
 ('TOKEN', 'i.d'),
 ('INFIX', '.'),
 ('TOKEN', 'OPf'),
 ('SUFFIX', '..')]
```

meaning you have splitting problems due to `SUFFIX` rules.

Then you may achieve what you want with redefining suffix patterns:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_md')
suffixes = (r"[\.]")
# suffixes = [r"[\.]"] + nlp.Defaults.suffixes[:38] + nlp.Defaults.suffixes[39:]

suffix_regex = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)
nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search = suffix_regex.search

doc = nlp('92637 Weiden i.d.OPf..')
[tok for tok in doc]
# expected result
[92637, Weiden, i.d, ., OPf, ., .]
```

Comment: In this example, you lose the default suffixes, right?

Comment: What do you think about this solve?
```suffixes = list(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)
suffixes.remove('\.\.+')
suffixes.append('\.\.\.+')```

Comment: we remove the default suffix that looks at 2 or more dots in a row and add a suffix that looks at 3 or more dots in a row. Thus, we have the ability to split them into two separate dots by adding a dot rule to the infixes

Comment: @Zimovik007 I answered the question "as it is", providing desired result (see my request for clarification and related answer in the comments to OP). Concerning your inquiry if we loose default suffixes I showed 2 solutions: with and without default suffixes. Concerning your solution, why not if it works.